# Theme color was changed after visiting site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I have SP 2019 on-prem environment. Created the subsite using Communication Template (As of now I was unable to create the Subsite using Communication Template so I found some trick to create it - [Reference URL](https://hangconsult.com/2017/06/29/change-sharepoint-online-root-site-collection-to-use-the-new-communication-site-template/)). 
Then I applied the Orange theme on a Site collection, Blue color on Subsites. 
The problem was when I visit the root site collection, then the subsite theme color was changing to Orange. This is happened only after visiting the Root site collection (Orange theme).
Also, I have checked with Default Team site template same problem occurs

Anyone experienced with this type of Problem or Can anyone suggest any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided, it seems to save site as template to accomplish it.

However, the "Save site as template" action is not supported on Communication sites.

Comment: I have also checked with default template Team site on Site Collection and Subsite same problem occurred

Comment: Yes it's a known issue, currently there is no official solution to resolve it.Please refer below link:https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3611

Comment: Thanks for Sharing!!